# How to create a HTML table with TCL

Tags: tcl

I have two variables, let's say `$a` with the list name & `$b` with age, how to generate an HTML web page with table format of name & age?

```
     puts $outfile "Name:$a Age:$b"
     set outfile [open "result_cell_pin.html" w+]
```

Without the help of packages...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick-and-dirty variant:

```
set data [list Name $a Age $b]

puts $outfile "<html>\n<body>\n<table>\n<tr>\n
[join [lmap {h _} $data {format <th>%s</th>\n $h}] {}]
</tr><tr>
[join [lmap {_ d} $data {format <td>%s</td>\n $d}] {}]
</tr>\n</table>\n</body>\n</html>"
```

This kind of solution does not scale, however. It's a little better to script the creation of html code, to make it easier to make it regular:

```
set a Reynard
set b 12

set data [list Name $a Age $b]

set level 0
set html {}

proc indent n {
    string repeat {    } $n
}

proc structuralElement {name body} {
    append ::html [indent $::level]<$name>\n
    incr ::level
    uplevel 1 $body
    incr ::level -1
    append ::html [indent $::level]</$name>\n
}

proc valueElement {name value} {
    append ::html [indent $::level]<$name>$value</$name>\n
}

structuralElement html {
    structuralElement body {
        structuralElement table {
            structuralElement tr {
                foreach {h _} $data {valueElement th $h}
            }
            structuralElement tr {
                foreach {_ d} $data {valueElement td $d}
            }
        }
    }
}

set outfile [open "result_cell_pin.html" w+]
puts $outfile $html
close $outfile
```

---

But there is no need to reinvent the wheel. The easiest way is probably to use tDOM. It looks messy but is very smooth when one gets used to it:

```
package require tdom

set doc [dom createDocument html]
set root [$doc documentElement]

dom createNodeCmd elementNode body
dom createNodeCmd elementNode table
dom createNodeCmd elementNode tr
dom createNodeCmd elementNode th
dom createNodeCmd elementNode td
dom createNodeCmd textNode t

set a Reynard
set b 12

set data [list Name $a Age $b]

$root appendFromScript {
    body {
        table {
            tr {
                dict for {h _} $data {th {t $h}}
            }
            tr {
                dict for {_ d} $data {td {t $d}}
            }
        }
    }
}

set outfile [open "result_cell_pin.html" w+]
puts $outfile [$doc asXML]
close $outfile
$doc delete
```

Why bother scripting it? There are a number of reasons, such as it being easier to get it right and it being easier to maintain. One major advantage is that it is a lot easier to adapt a script when the specifications change. Say that you now have multiple values in `a` and `b` that you need to show on multiple rows in the table. Rewriting the first code example is a bother, but rewriting the tdom script is a breeze:

```
set a {Reynard Antimony Jones}
set b {12 16 3.7e09}

set data [list Name $a Age $b]

$root appendFromScript {
    body {
        table {
            tr {
                dict for {h _} $data {th {t $h}}
            }
        foreach d1 $a d2 $b {
            tr {
                td {t $d1}
                td {t $d2}
            }
        }
        }
    }
}
```

Don’t be afraid of packages. Tcl is a small-kernel language where a lot of the functionality that other languages have built-in is stored in packages. There is no real difference between using advance file-handling functions in Language X and loading the `fileutil` package to use the same commands in Tcl.

Documentation:
[append](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/append.htm),
[close](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/close.htm),
[dict](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/dict.htm),
[foreach](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm),
[format](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/format.htm),
[incr](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/incr.htm),
[join](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/join.htm),
[list](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/list.htm),
[lmap (for Tcl 8.5)](http://wiki.tcl.tk/40570),
[lmap](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lmap.htm),
[open](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/open.htm),
[package](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/package.htm),
[proc](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/proc.htm),
[puts](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/puts.htm),
[set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm),
[string](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm),
[tdom (package)](http://tdom.github.io),
[uplevel](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/uplevel.htm)

Comment: Thanks for much needed feedback, l think I do not have v8.6, so it pops an error as invalid command name "lmap"

Comment: @CLEX420: if you have 8.5, you can use the replacement code for lmap linked to in the documentation list above. If not, foreach and lappend in combination does the same job.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend giving 'html' package a try.
http://wiki.tcl.tk/38727

```
% package require html
1.3
% foreach supportedMethod [info procs ::html::*] {
>    puts $supportedMethod
>}
::html::tableFromList
::html::keywords
::html::passwordInput
::html::radioValue
::html::quoteFormValue
::html::eval
::html::selectPlain
::html::textarea
::html::meta
::html::getTitle
::html::closeTag
::html::tagParam
::html::openTag
::html::if
::html::cell
::html::html_entities
::html::h1
::html::title
::html::checkSet
::html::h2
::html::passwordInputRow
::html::radioSet
::html::h3
::html::h4
::html::h5
::html::h6
::html::for
::html::select
::html::varEmpty
::html::formValue
::html::minorMenu
::html::bodyTag
::html::set
::html::description
::html::textInput
::html::mailto
::html::font
::html::h
::html::while
::html::head
::html::extractParam
::html::textInputRow
::html::refresh
::html::nl2br
::html::foreach
::html::getFormInfo
::html::row
::html::tableFromArray
::html::author
::html::checkValue
::html::init
::html::submit
::html::default
::html::checkbox
::html::end
::html::minorList
::html::paramRow
::html::urlParent
::html::headTag
::html::hdrRow
% ::html::tableFromList [list a1 a2 a3 a4 a5]
<TABLE ><tr>
    <td>a1</td>
    <td>a2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>a3</td>
    <td>a4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>a5</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
</TABLE>
% array set x [list a1 b1 a2 b2 a3 b3]
% ::html::tableFromArray x
<TABLE >
<TR><TH colspan=2>x</TH></TR>
<tr>
    <td>a1</td>
    <td>b1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>a2</td>
    <td>b2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>a3</td>
    <td>b3</td>
</tr>
</TABLE>

%
```

Comment: Note that the keys go into the left column instead of the top row.

Comment: @PeterLewerin: Thanks!